# if $A\times B = A$, is $B ={} $Identity matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A, B ∈ M_{n×n}$

If   $A\cdot B = A  $, then $B$ is the identity matrix.

I can't find a theorem that proves this statement. Could it be false?

Edit:

A is NOT the zero matrix.

Comment: @gen-ℤreadytoperish Except matrix product isn't commutative, thus it is false.

Comment: it would be true if $A$ is invertible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A  counterexample*:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\quad B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$
$AB=A$ only means that $B-I$ belongs to the annihilator of $A$ in the ring $M_{n\times n}$.

Answer (score 2):

It's false. $A$ could be the zero matrix, then $B$ could be absolutely any matrix.

Comment: I guess the  O.p. implicitly thought of a non-zero matrix.